Original source "GF92" for two drawings of Dirac belt trick

I am trying to track down the original source/artist of these two drawings of the Dirac belt trick (see link below) to use in my thesis (which is in mathematics, but I believe these pictures likely come from a physics source). The earliest source I can find is a blog post Qué es el espín de una partícula. I contacted the author of that blog post, but in case I don't get a response I am wondering if anyone here can help me track it down.
I wasn't sure whether I should post this in the Physics or the History of Science and Mathematics Stackexchanges, but I'm guessing the source is from 1992 which may not be long enough ago to call "history."

You may enjoy Greg Egan's animated version: https://www.gregegan.net/APPLETS/21/21.html

I expect from the drawing style that the "GF92"  is George Francis  but it's not in his "A Topological Picture Book". The closest there is the second  row  of 

I am convinced it is G. Francis. Still, I can't find the two drawings in his works around 1992. I sent him an email.
